# How to find the edges for the following graph I need to build?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Here's the question: Let S be a set which $S=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Let $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ be subsets of $S$ which aren't equal. We need to prove there is an $x$ in $S$ such that the union of $x$ with $A_1,A_2,$ $\ldots,A_n$ keeps them not equal. There's a clue: To build a graph that it's vertices are $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$. Now I've thought what the edges should be, and couldn't find the correct condition.

Thanks, Sergey

Comment: Do you mean that all the sets are pairwise distinct?

Comment: It's pairwise not equal, for example for n=2: A1={1}, A2={1,2} satisfies the definition but, A1={2}, A2={2] doesn't satisfy the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not necessary to prove with graphs I can suggest you another proof.
Let's $$|A_1|\le|A_2|\le\cdots\le|A_n|.$$ Suppose it is not true, so for every $k\in\{1,2,...,n\}$ there are $i_k,j_k\in\{1,2,...,n\}$, such that $A_{i_k}=A_{j_k}\setminus\{k\}$,i.e. $|A_{i_k}|=|A_{j_k}| - 1$. It is easy to see that it is contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
 But sorry I don't see the contradiction, the fact that|Aik|=|Ajk|−1 doesn't contradict the first assumption that all of the subsets aren't equal in the first place. What am I missing? should it contradict something else?

Comment: Can you see that there can be at most $n-1$ $(A_i,A_j)$ pairs, such that $|A_i| + 1 = |A_j|$?

Comment: I got it, thank you very much! I didn't think the solution can be so simple!